# Runtime exception while uploading image to the server

Tags: php, android, image-uploading, runtimeexception

The below is the `runtime exeception` which i got while am trying to upload a image to the server. 
[image]

And am trying to upload a image using my local server(WAMP) and my android code is

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Sunset.jpg");

     //   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background1); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.

            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));

            try{

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.49/android/upload_image.php");

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);

                Toast.makeText(uploadimage.this, "Response  " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch(Exception e){
                  Toast.makeText(uploadimage.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  System.out.println("Error  http   connection"+e.toString());
            }

        }

        public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

             String res = "";
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

             inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
             int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..

             Toast.makeText(uploadimage.this, "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             if (contentLength < 0){
             }
             else{
                    byte[] data = new byte[512];
                    int len = 0;

                    try
                    {
                        while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                        {

                            buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..

                        }

                    }

                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                     res = buffer.toString();     // converting string buffer to string

                    Toast.makeText(uploadimage.this, "Result : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

             }
  return res;

        }

}
```

and this is my php code which i got from internet .

```
<?php

    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];

     $binary=base64_decode($base);

    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

    $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');

    fwrite($file, $binary);

    fclose($file);

    echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';

?>
```

Can any one help me in this to solve my problem. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create one additional directory in c:\ then provide read, write and execute permission on it. 
In your php code please write the absolute path of the storage location.

This may solve your problem.

Remember to run the IIS server in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

Inetpub is created by the SYSTEM user. This means that you aren't allowed to make modifications to it, or any of its subdirectories, without admin permissions. Try changing the permissions of the inetpub folder so anyone can modify the files. Right-click -> Properties -> ... I forget what to do after that. (I'm in Linux right now). If that doesn't work, make sure you are running IIS as an Administrator.